# Не корректно сохраняются данные авторизации (Cookie, Php)

Tags: php, cookie

Есть код сохранения хэша пользователя (Запомнить меня):

```
    $this->query("UPDATE users SET hash = ?s WHERE id = ?i", $hash, $_SESSION['id']);
setcookie("hash", $hash , time()+60*60*24*30, "/", ".example.com");
```

Простая функция проверки:

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE['hash'])) {
    $hash = $db->getRow("SELECT id,user FROM users WHERE hash = ?s", $_COOKIE['hash']);
    if (!empty($hash)) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $hash['user'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = intval($hash['id']);
    }
```

Все работает идеально, что у меня, что на других компьютерах. Но очень часто поступают жалобы от пользователей сайта, что при закрытии браузера приходится заново авторизоватся. По всей видимости они используют либо старые браузеры, либо старую ОС (к примеру XP).

Не подскажите что тут не так, и что не подходит для других браузеров? Возможно  код сохранения куки не очень корректный? (куки должны быть видимы и для поддоменов веб сайта)

Comment: А эти жалующиеся пользователи не желают сообщить версии своих браузеров и ОС?)

Comment: Кстати, есть предположение, что дело может быть в том, что жалующиеся пользователи используют два и более браузера, а hash у вас всего один

Comment: В куке можно передать и id, и хеш хеша, и время истечения куки, и хеш всего этого разом. И тогда можно в 10 браузерах залогиниться и ни чего вылетать не будет.

Comment: Сделал хэш из $_SESSION['user'], теперь точно не должно возникнуть проблем, с перезаписью хэша. Будем проверять

Comment: Вы бы кроме имени юзера для генерации еще и хеш пароля брали, а то вдруг у двух разных юзеров имена будут одинаковые.

Comment: @Visman как раз таки **имя пользователя** - уникальное,  не чувствительно к регистру, так что этого точно не произойдет.

Comment: А если будете использовать и хеш пароля, то при его смене юзер будет разлогиниться (<-- странно слово) во всех браузерах ;) P..S. Хотя если там сессии еще живы, то не будет :(